# User Friendly Registration System

Tags: php, mysql, html, user-interface, user-experience

I need to build a registration system which requires the collection of large data (many fields) from the user registering which is then inserted into a couple of tables in a database.

I don't really want to display a very long form to the user for the purposes of better UX.
This system will not run online, it is just a web app to run on the desktop.

I need help, pointers, references, etc on how I can better organize the registration process to make it more user friendly.

This [How to encourage a user to fill in long application forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232519/how-to-encourage-a-user-to-fill-in-long-application-forms) has been helpful so far

Comment: They usually do this sort of thing in a few page/step process. that way by the time they realise how long the registration process is, they are already half way done heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't mind requiring your user has Javascript, I would use AJAX.  Let's say that you have 50 fields that you can logically combine into 4 different sets - the first may be about the person asking for name, email, etc., while the next set asks for historical information or employment information - like on an application.

Make one form for each set, and then present a new user with the first.  When he completes the first page, instead of a "Submit" or "Register" button, use an AJAX call and a "Next" button to get the info and switch to the next page of the form with the next set of fields.  You could use the AJAX calls to hold the information in a temp table in your database, and then, once the entire process is complete, you can write it to your member/users table.

You could do like other surveys or checkouts do and add a "title" for each page of the form above the form fields so that as a user moves through registration, they can monitor their own progress.

I'd recommend checking out the Amazon checkout, or really any multi-page survey (you may even be able to set one up yourself on Survey Monkey) to see how a large number of form fields can be broken down logically in a user friendly way.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/05/innovative-techniques-to-simplify-signups-and-logins/

It's talking about login- and registration-forms and how to make them more user-friendly. A suggestion which is also included in this article is as follows:

At registration don't ask the user to many questions. Only the basic data like their name for example. Then ask him about more detailed data when the user logs in the first time. This way the registration won't take too long.

Maybe this helps you out :)

Comment: Great, helpful. This one http://designshack.co.uk/articles/inspiration/20-great-sign-up-form-examples-to-learn-from too